# Namespace 'fab' is not bound error when using com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, xml, android-view, floating-action-button

am trying to create a floating action menu using the [Clans/FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1684) but i am getting the namespace 'fab' is not bound error in my layout file. I have included the dependency of `compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'` so i don't know what is wrong.

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.kabricks.betterapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
        app:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
        fab:menu_fab_label="Floating Action Menu"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66aff198"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 1"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_photo"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 2"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
            fab:fab_label="Menu Item 3"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />
    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is the error,

```
Error:(26) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

I am using Android studio 2.2 and design library `23.3.0`

Comment: Try to rebuild project

Comment: Add this to root layout: `xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.github.clans"`

Comment: I have, but its still not working

Comment: YOu need to automatically detect fab:  `xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

Comment: @azizbekian it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to root layout:

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.github.cla‌​ns"
```